Are the rings of holomorphic functions over a domain $D\subset\mathbb{C}$ isomorphic for different $D$?
Let $D\subset\mathbb{C}$ be a domain (i.e., open connected set), and $\mathcal{O}(D)$ be the ring of holomorphic functions over $D$. I hope that this is not a silly question, but do we have $\mathcal{O}(D)\cong\mathcal{O}(D')$ as rings for different $D$ and $D'$? In particular, do we have $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C})\cong\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{D})$, where $\mathbb{D}$ is the open unit disk? We know that $\mathcal{O}(D)$ is always a Bezout domain that is not a UFD (see Lemma 3.16 and Proposition 4.4 of here).
Thank you for any help.

For simply connected domains $\not = \Bbb C$, it seems to follow from the Riemann mapping theorem.

It would be nice if the person who downvoted and voted to closed could give their specific reason; this question has received canonical answers.

Note first that the map $(\Phi f)(\bar z)=\overline {f(\bar z)}, z \in D$ gives a ring isomorphism between $\mathcal O(D)$ and $\mathcal O(\bar D)$ but $D$ and $\bar D$ are not in general conformally equivalent (this can happen for $4$ connected - meaning the first homology group is $\mathbb Z^3$ or that they have $4$ (nontrivial) boundary components - domains already - eg the annulus $1<|z|<2$ minus two small disjoint inside discs above the $x$ axis). We show that if $D$ or $D'$ admit nonconstant bounded analytic functions (which most domains do - this happens as long as the boundary doesn't consist of isolated points) this is the only possible situation where we do not get conformal equivalence between the domains, though then one is conformally equivalent to the conjugate of the other domain - so for example $\mathcal O(\mathbb D)$ and $\mathcal O(\mathbb C)$ are not isomorphic.
We denote by $a_D(z)=a, a_{D'}(w)=a$ the corresponding constant functions for a complex number $a$.
Note that $\Phi(1_D)=1_{D'}$ since $1_D$ is the multiplicative unit of $\mathcal O(D)$. Then as usual $\Phi(q_D)=q_{D'}$ for any rational $q$ by additivity.
Then for any $a \notin \mathbb Q$ we have $\Phi(a_D-q_D)=\phi(a_D)-q_{D'}$ doesn't vanish for any rational $q$ and since $\Phi(a_D)$ is holomorphic so open if not constant, it follows $\Phi(a_D)$ is constant (and an automorphism of $\mathbb C$). Also note that $\Phi(i_D)=\pm i_{D'}$, hence $\Phi((q+ir)_D)=q_{D'} \pm (ir)_{D}$ for rationals $q,r$
Now let's assume $|f| \le M$ bounded and nonconstant, so $f-a_D$ doesn't vanish for any complex $a$ with rational real and imaginary parts and absolute value greater than $M$ so by the above $\Phi(f)-a_{D'}$ doesn't also vanish, which means $|\Phi(f)| \le M$ again by the open mapping theorem (since $f$ nonconstant $\Phi(f)$ is nonconstant by the discussion above).
In particular since either $D$ or $D'$ admit nonconstant bounded analytic functions by our assumption above, picking one $|f| \le M$ in $D$ say, we get that for all $|a| \le 1$ we have $|f-a_D| \le M+1$ so $|\Phi(f)| \le M, |\Phi(f-a_D)| \le M+1$ so $|\Phi(a)_{D'}| \le 2M+1$ which by well known results implies that the $\mathbb C$ automorphism $\Phi$ is regular hence is the identity or the conjugation on the complex numbers.
If $\Phi$ is the identity on the complex numbers, the proof by @Matsimir shows that $D$ and $D'$ are conformally equivalent and $\Phi$ comes in the usual way from a conformal equivalence map between the two.
If $\Phi$ is the conjugation then composing it with the above isomorphism between $\mathcal O(D)$ and $\mathcal O(\bar D)$ gives us an isomorphism $\Psi$ between  $\mathcal O(\bar D)$  and $\mathcal O(D')$ which is the identity restricted to the complex numbers (regarded as the constant functions as above) and we are done.

That's nice! Thanks :)

happy to be of help

There is a complete answer to your question, if we replace the word ''ring'' with ''$\mathbb C$-algebra''. The precise statement is that $\mathcal O(D)$ and $\mathcal O(D')$ are isomorphic as $\mathbb C$-algebras if and only if there is a biholomorphic mapping $D \rightarrow D'$. The initial question where $\mathcal O(D)$ and $\mathcal O(D')$ are considered as rings seems to be much more subtle, and I can't even come up with an answer for $D = \mathbb D$ and $D' = \mathbb C$.
The proof of the following statement should be clear.
Proposition 1. Let $\phi:D \rightarrow D'$ be a holomorphic mapping. Then the mapping $C_\phi:\mathcal O(D') \rightarrow \mathcal O(D)$ given as $C_\phi(f) = f \circ \phi$ is a unital $\mathbb C$-algebra homomorphism. It is an isomorphism if and only if $\phi$ is biholomorphic.
Now I claim that all unital homomorphisms of $\mathbb C$-algebras $\Phi:\mathcal O(D') \rightarrow \mathcal O(D)$ can be expressed as $C_\phi$ for a suitable holomorphic $\phi:D \rightarrow D'$.
Proposition 2. Let $\Phi:\mathcal O(D') \rightarrow \mathcal O(D)$ be a unital homomorphism of $\mathbb C$-algebras and let $\phi = \Phi(\mathrm{id}_{D'})$ (here $\mathrm{id}_{D'} \in \mathcal O(D')$ denotes the identity function). Then $\Phi = C_\phi$.
Proof. At first we check that $\phi(D) \subset D'$. Consider $z \in \mathbb C \setminus D'$. Clearly, $\mathrm{id}_{D'} - z$ is invertible in $\mathcal O(D')$, so $\Phi(\mathrm{id}_{D'} - z) = \phi - z$ is invertible in $\mathcal O(D)$. Therefore, $z \notin \phi(D)$. Thus, we can, indeed, consider a homomorphism $C_\phi:\mathcal O(D') \rightarrow \mathcal O(D)$.
Let $f \in \mathcal O(D')$. We wish to prove that $\Phi(f)(z) = f(\phi(z))$ for all $z \in D$. Fix $z \in D$ and let $c = f(\phi(z))$. Since $f - c$ has a zero at $\phi(z)$, there exists $g \in \mathcal O(D')$ such that $f - c = (\mathrm{id}_{D'} - \phi(z)) g$. Thus, $\Phi(f - c) = \Phi((\mathrm{id}_{D'} - \phi(z)) g) = (\phi - \phi(z))\Phi(g)$ vanishes at $z$. Thus, $\Phi(f)(z) = c$. $\blacksquare$
Remark. What we really proved is the fact that the correspondence $D \rightarrow \mathcal O(D)$, $\phi \rightarrow C_\phi$ is a contravariant equivalence of the category of open subsets in $\mathbb C$ with holomorphic mappings as morphisms onto some full subcategory in the category of unital $\mathbb C$-algebras.
Proposition 3. $\mathcal O(D)$ and $\mathcal O(D')$ are isomorphic as $\mathbb C$-algebras if and only if there is a biholomorphic mapping $D \rightarrow D'$.
Proof. If $\phi:D \rightarrow D'$ is a biholomoprhic mapping, then $C_\phi:\mathcal O(D') \rightarrow \mathcal O(D)$ is an isomoprhism by Proposition 1. This proves the ''if'' part. To prove the ''only if'' let $\Phi:\mathcal O(D') \rightarrow \mathcal O(D)$ be an isomorphism and consider (by Proposition 2) $\phi:D \rightarrow D'$ such that $\Phi = C_\phi$. By Proposition 1, $\phi$ is biholomorphic. $\blacksquare$
Since there is no biholomorphic mapping $\mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb D$ due to Liouville's theorem, we get the following
Corollary. $\mathbb C$-algebras $\mathcal O(\mathbb D)$ and $\mathcal O(\mathbb C)$ are not isomoprhic.

Sorry for the stupid question. In which part are you using the $\mathbb{C}$-algebra structure?

@SeverinSchraven In the proof of Proposition 2 several times I used that $\Phi(a) = a$ for constants $a \in \mathbb C$.

Thanks! Indeed, I've completely missed that.

the result should follow for ring isomorphisms only using a few facts about the structure of  $\mathcal O(D)$ - for example the only maximal principal ideals are $(z-c)O(D), c \in D$ so any ring isomorphism between $\mathcal O(D')$ and $\mathcal O(D')$  gives rise to a bijective map from $D'$ to $D$ and then one has to prove that must be holomorphic etc

Thanks! That's an interesting result, at least you have proved that $\mathcal{O}(D)$ and $\mathcal{O}(D')$ don't have "well-behaved" ring isomorphisms (i.e., preserving constant functions) if $D$ and $D'$ are not biholomorphically equivalent. I would be willing to accept this answer, but I'm not sure about the consensus in this community.

@Conrad I thought of that, but was not able to progress in this direction. Indeed, given a ring isomorphism $\Phi:\mathcal O(D') \rightarrow \mathcal O(D)$ we have a corresponding bijection $\phi:D \rightarrow D'$ such that $f(\phi(z)) = 0$ iff $\Phi(f)(z) = 0$. Moreover, the value $f(\phi(z))$ is mapped to $f(z)$ by a field automorphism $\alpha_z$ of $\mathbb C$. This would be enough provided that the field $\mathbb C$ does not have nontrivial automorphisms. For me it is not clear whether it is possible to have nonholomorphic $\phi$ with a peculiar choice of corresponding automorphisms.

gave a proof that for most domains at least (one of $D$, $D'$ has nontrivial boundary - in other words the boundary doesn;t consist only of isolated points) that is the only thing that can happen ($\alpha_z$ must be identity or conjugation) - though in general $D$ and $\bar D$ are not conformally equivalent but their rings of holomorphic functions are trivially isomorphic by double conjugation $f \to \overline{f(\bar z)}$

@Conrad very nice idea to use open mapping theorem along with stability of rational numbers under field automorphisms!
